# Blur content behind a div using CSS3

Tags: css

I've encountered a problem with applying blur to the background of absolute/fixed elements, as it does not seem to blur the main content of the page, only the content of the absolute element itself. I currently have the styling for my alert as following:

```
.alert-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.alert-wrap .alert {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(215, 44, 44, 0.5);
    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.alert-wrap .alert:before {
    content: "";

    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);

}
```

I'm looking to have this blur the background of the alert element, making the main content behind it seem blurred (applying more focus on the element itself), but have not managed to find anything even confirming this issue exists at all.

HTML document flow is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Header Stuff Deleted -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='alert-wrap'>
            <div class='alert'>
                <div class='head'>
                    Notifications
                </div>
                <div class='body'>
                    Alert content here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
            //constructing navbar
        ?>

        <div class='content'>
            Some content here
        </div>

        <?php
            //constructing footer
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Image example:

[image: example]

Comment: You have a problem, because you don't have any background applied to the blurred element, so there is nothing to blur.

Comment: @makshh As I said in the OP, I'm looking to blur the background of the absolute element to make the content behind the semi transparent background blurry, not the any sort of background of the element itself.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYMQBW

Comment: @makshh I'm probably not doing a great job of explaining this, I'll add some images

Comment: @makshh Image example: [img](http://i.imgur.com/rJIb4BM.png)

Comment: I see, I think it will be hard to reproduce this, because you would have to blur the exact part of the image/content beneath the alert.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388840/can-you-blur-the-content-beneath-behind-a-div

Answer (score 11):

Best solution:

```
backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
```

Also available in webkit:

```
-webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
```

Answer (score 7):

I have updated this for your comment about blurring the content... this is better handled [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/krtocoxy/).

This will blur the background and all content, but not the alert.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="alert">
    Lorum Ipsum Delorum Alert!
</div>

<div class="content" id="example">
    Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 

    <div onclick="document.getElementById('example').className='alerting';document.getElementById('alert').style.display='block';">Go</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {

}

.alerting {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}

#alert {
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually looking to blur content that is below my alert to place more focus on the alert itself, I've seen this solution a few times while searching, thank you anyways.

Comment: I have updated to blur all content except the alert.

Comment: Not exactly, I'll add some images to the OP to make it more clear hopefully

Comment: It is technically possible, but economically impossible :) You would need to create a clone of the content, sized to fit exactly behind the alert in an element with overflow hidden... and scrolled to the appropriate position. Then you could blur that clone hosting element. That would be quite a lot of work.

Comment: Fair enough, looks like I'll have to find something else. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687846/using-a-div-to-blur-an-image-behind-it/19688466#19688466). The CSS blur filter applies to the element itself; however `background-filter` was [recently introduced in the webkit nightly](https://www.webkit.org/blog/3632/introducing-backdrop-filters/). For a fallback that works in current browsers -- albeit using canvas -- check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687846/using-a-div-to-blur-an-image-behind-it/19688466#19688466)

Comment: *backdrop-filter